# Finding limiting distribution of $Y_n/\sqrt{n}$

Tags: limits, statistics, probability-distributions

Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be independent and identically distributed discrete uniform random variables over the set $S_n := \{1, ..., n\}$.

We define $Y_n = \text{min} \{k:\exists l < k : X_l=X_k\}$

PROBLEM I WISH TO SOLVE:

> Compute the limiting distribution of $Y_n/\sqrt{n}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

My attempt so far is as follows:

For fixed $n$, $$P(Y_n > y) = P(X_1, ..., X_{\lfloor y \rfloor} \text{are distinct}) = \frac{n!}{n^{\lfloor y \rfloor}(n-\lfloor y \rfloor)!}$$

(for $y \in [2, n+1)$ - this probability is $1$ if $y < 2$ and 0 for $y \ge n+1$).  The first equality follows by definition and the second follows since we simply pick $\lfloor y \rfloor$ values from $S_n$, and assign to each of $X_1, ..., X_{\lfloor y \rfloor}$ with probability $1/n$.

My final problem is simply to compute

$$\text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(Y_n > y\sqrt{n}) = \text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n!}{n^{\lfloor y\sqrt{n} \rfloor}(n-\lfloor y \sqrt{n}\rfloor)!}$$

I've tried using Stirling's formula to simplify but I really have no clue how to proceed since it isn't working for me.  Please help if you can!

EDIT:
Answer is here for anyone curious: [Computing $\text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n!}{n^{\lfloor y\sqrt{n} \rfloor}(n-\lfloor y \sqrt{n}\rfloor)!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3457549/computing-textlim-n-rightarrow-infty-fracnn-lfloor-y-sqrtn-rflo/3457575?noredirect=1#comment7107822_3457575)

Comment: You should look at the Central Limit Theorem. From a quick glance I'm guessing $X_l$ has mean 1 and variance 1. I might come back later and provide an answer. Or I might be talking out of my ass.

Comment: I do not see how the CLT applied here at all.  I just need the limit for the cdf which can be taken as 1 minus the limit I'm trying to calculate above.

Comment: I've removed the tag [tag:probability-theory]. Please read the tag summary when using a tag. Also, please don't intentionally duplicate questions. I've voted to close this one as a duplicate of the one that's been answered.